# How to iterate over Pandas rows while updating a series of rows based on a loc condition?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lambda

I have a time series table of inventory with a function that tells me whether I have to restock based on quantity (if available is less than 10, restock)

I need to iterate over each row to subtract the amount of DVDs rented every day from my available inventory so that I can flag days where I need to restock.

How would I be able to update a window of rows to add the amount in an iterable way? There's no real way to use vectoring/loc because there are functions reliant on data for that current row

Example:

```
date       dvd  avail rented    buy more?
1/1/2018    a   10  2   N
1/1/2018    b   20  4   N
1/2/2018    a   11  3   N
1/2/2018    b   28  2   N
1/3/2018    a   14  5   N
1/3/2018    b   28  6   N
```

What I need:

```
date    dvd avail rented rolling_rentals    buy more?   bought
1/1/2018    a   10  2   0   N   0
1/1/2018    b   20  4   0   N   0
1/2/2018    a   9   3   2   Y   1
1/2/2018    b   24  2   4   N   0
1/3/2018    a   9   5   5   Y   1
1/3/2018    b   22  6   6   N   0
```

Comment: How is the `rolling_rentals` calculated here?

Comment: it is a rolling sum of the rented. So for example a rolling 5 day would get the rolling sum of past 5 days (for 1/3 it's 2+3 = 5)

Comment: Is the `available` column in your sample dataframe already being subtracted from? Or does the `available` column also just change on it's own?

Comment: the available is independent- there can be different returns that aren't reflected in this table

Comment: So why does the first row not have a `Y` in `buy more?` column? 10 - 2 = 8, which is less than 10?

Comment: it's rolling and doesn't include that day, which is why rolling_rentals is 0 in that column. you don't include rented for that day in the rolling_rental

Comment: Ok, so is the `bought` column supposed to be just `0` or `1` to represent `True` or `False`? If it's supposed to be the quantity that you are short of `10`, then your example does not make sense since your are subtracting `rented` from `avail`

Comment: I am subtracting the rolling sum of rented from available on that day. So I'm taking 11 - 2 = 9, 14 - 5 = 9  and to make it up to 10 I need to buy another dvd. does that make sense?